# Google Identity Toolkit: Android client ID

Tags: android, google-identity-toolkit

I have been playing with the GIT for a while now, and I am a bit confused with  the two client IDs in AndroidManifest

```
android:scheme="INSERT_REVERSED_SERVER_CLIENT_ID"
android:name="identitytoolkit.server_client_id"
android:value="INSERT_YOUR_SERVER_CLIENT_ID"
```

It looks like changing the value of [android:scheme] does not have any effect on GIT. And for some reason for [identitytoolkit.server_client_id] I can only use web client ID. If I plug in Android client ID from the dev console, GIT fails for Google accounts.

Could somebody please explain how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Android Manifest should look roughly like this:

```
...
<application>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <!-- The scheme value is the reversed web Application Client ID -->
            <data
                android:host="gitkit"
                android:scheme="com.googleusercontent.apps.[SOME NUMBERS]-[SOME NUMBERS AND LETTERS]" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="identitytoolkit.server_client_id"
        android:value="[SOME NUMBERS]-[SOME NUMBERS AND LETTERS].apps.googleusercontent.com" />

</application>
...
```

Both [SOME NUMBERS] replacement values should match exactly, as should both [SOME NUMBERS AND LETTERS] replacement values. This Client ID is generated by Google when you create a new OAuth 2.0 Client ID of type "Web application." I know, it seems weird that you have to create a Web application client ID for your android app, but you do.

You can see [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/android/quickstart#step_3_set_up_the_quick-start_app) for further help! Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply, the main question is what is the purpose of android:scheme value, because changing it does not seem to affect the functionality

Comment: Check out [this link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1H255a9QacH06Z9-239xAOEixbR967RmLu7-o0siRaJg/edit#heading=h.7an6cb81mdm2). Look for the section entitled **Register your mobile app to listen on a custom URL scheme**. It states "... you should choose a unique URL scheme so that it doesn't conflict with others'." It later states "[y]ou can name it any value, but the convention is to use a reverse domain style." It doesn't matter what it is, but if you use your reverse domain, you are guaranteed it won't conflict with others' schemes, thereby ensuring that your scheme is indeed unique.